# How to understand if exec.cmd was canceled

Tags: go, exec

I'm trying to return specific error when the command was canceled by context.
After investigating ProcessState understood that if got -1 in exitCode the process got terminate signal
https://golang.org/pkg/os/#ProcessState.ExitCode
but maybe we have more elegant way? 
Maybe I can put this error from cancel function? 
Maybe it isn't good enough exitCode for understanding if the command was canceled?

```
var (
    CmdParamsErr = errors.New("failed to get params for execution command")
    ExecutionCanceled = errors.New("command canceled")
)

func execute(m My) error {
    filePath, args, err := cmdParams(m)
    err = nil
    if err != nil {
        log.Infof("cmdParams: err: %v\n, m: %v\n", err, m)
        return CmdParamsErr
    }

    var out bytes.Buffer
    var errStd bytes.Buffer
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 2*time.Second)
    defer cancel()
    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, filePath, args...)
    cmd.Stdout = &out
    cmd.Stderr = &errStd
    err = cmd.Run()
    if err != nil {
        if cmd.ProcessState.ExitCode() == -1 {
            log.Warnf("execution was canceled by signal, err: %v\n", err)
            err = ExecutionCanceled
            return err
        } else {
            log.Errorf("run failed, err: %v, filePath: %v, args: %v\n", err, filePath, args)
            return err
        }
    }
    return err
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no straightforward or elegant way to figure out if a process was killed because a context was canceled. The closest you can come is this:

```
func run() error {
    ctx, cancel := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), 1*time.Second)
    defer cancel()

    cmd := exec.CommandContext(ctx, "bash", "-c", "exit 1")

    // Start() returns an error if the process can't be started. It will return
    // ctx.Err() if the context is expired before starting the process.

    if err := cmd.Start(); err != nil {
        return err
    }

    if err := cmd.Wait(); err != nil {
        if e, ok := err.(*exec.ExitError); ok {

            // If the process exited by itself, just return the error to the
            // caller.

            if e.Exited() {
                return e
            }

            // We know now that the process could be started, but didn't exit
            // by itself. Something must have killed it. If the context is done,
            // we can *assume* that it has been killed by the exec.Command.
            // Let's return ctx.Err() so our user knows that this *might* be
            // the case.

            select {
            case <-ctx.Done():
                return ctx.Err()
            default:
                return e
            }
        }

        return err
    }

    return nil
}
```

The problem here is that there might be a race condition, so returning `ctx.Err()` might be misleading. For example, imagine the following scenario:

1. The process starts.
2. The process is killed by an external actor.
3. The context is canceled.
4. You check the context.

At this point, the function above would return `ctx.Err()`, but this might be misleading because the reason why the process was killed is not because the context was canceled. If you decide to use a code similar to the function above, keep in mind this approximation.

Answer (score 1):

[exec.ExitError](https://golang.org/pkg/os/exec/#ExitError) doesn't provide any reason for the exit code (there is no relevant struct field nor an Unwrap method), so you have to check the context directly:

```
if ctx.Err() != nil {
    log.Println("canceled")
}
```

Note that this is a slight race because the context may be canceled just after the command failed for a different reason, but there is nothing you can do about that.